# Unable to Install Go-Ipfs from source

Tags: go, ipfs

I'm trying to Build IPFS from Source on windows 10.

Previously i installed it from source.It was working fine. But i needed the latest source so i started again from the scratch. because i edited some parts in the source.

I followed instructions on https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/docs/windows.md.

I received following error on executing following commands.

code

```
cd %GOPATH%\src\github.com\ipfs\go-ipfs
make install
```

Error

```
go version go1.12.6 windows/amd64
bin/check_go_version 1.12
go install  -asmflags=all=-trimpath="D:\GO_WORKSPACE" -gcflags=all=-trimpath="D:\GO_WORKSPACE" -ldflags="-X "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs".CurrentCommit=810cb607e-dirty" ./cmd/ipfs
# github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/plugin/loader
plugin\loader\preload.go:11:2: undefined: pluginipldgit
plugin\loader\preload.go:12:2: undefined: pluginbadgerds
plugin\loader\preload.go:13:2: undefined: pluginflatfs
plugin\loader\preload.go:14:2: undefined: pluginlevelds
make: *** [cmd/ipfs/Rules.mk:37: cmd/ipfs-install] Error 2
```

I tried Adding this plugins in to preload.go file under src\github.com\ipfs\go-ipfs\plugin\loader directory.

exisiting code on preload.go.

```
import (
    "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/plugin"
)
```

i added after the issue

```
import (
    "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/plugin"
    pluginipldgit "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/plugin/plugins/git"
    pluginbadgerds "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/plugin/plugins/git"
    pluginflatfs "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/plugin/plugins/git"
    pluginlevelds "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/plugin/plugins/git"
)
```

so after i added this lines result is success.

Executed command

```
make install
```

Result

```
go version go1.12.6 windows/amd64
bin/check_go_version 1.12
go install  -asmflags=all=-trimpath="D:\GO_WORKSPACE" -gcflags=all=-trimpath="D:\GO_WORKSPACE" -ldflags="-X "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs".CurrentCommit=810cb607e-dirty" ./cmd/ipfs
```

Then i tried to start the ipfs using following command

```
ipfs daemon
```

Error

```
Initializing daemon...
go-ipfs version: 0.4.22-dev-810cb607e-dirty
Repo version: 7
System version: amd64/windows
Golang version: go1.12.6

Error: unknown datastore type: flatfs
```

Can someone help me configure the IPFS from source.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by following method. not sure this will be a good solution or not. any way i could solve the issue.

I'm posting this as a answer. so it will be useful to everyone who has the same issue.

1) Deleted go-ipfs folder inside the "%GO_WORKSPACE% / .... / ipfs" folder.

2) Git clone the go ipfs repo manually on the same location.

3) go inside go-ipfs folder.

4) execute install command.

```
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Done on Windows.

1. Save IPFS (kubo) to some folder inside %GOPATH% (I cloned https://github.com/ipfs/kubo) to folder `%GOPATH%\kubo`
2. **Important** `cd %GOPATH%\kubo\cmd\ipfs\`
3. `go install`

ipfs.exe was placed in `%GOPATH%\bin`
I launched it as daemon - works.
BTW: GOROOT is defined and path to go is included in PATH