# How to build IPFS (kubo) within JetBrains Goland?

Tags: go, build, ipfs, goland

I am new to golang. First to say I
**can** build kubo(go-ipfs) [with standard Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56760823/1544015) but didn't in Goland.
With standard Go.exe build I need to cd to the folder with the `main` module and main func and only then run: `go install`

Steps to reproduce in Golnad:

1. Installed Goland 2022.2.3
2. New Project - > from SCV Git: https://github.com/ipfs/kubo
3. Used suggested Goland path within C:\Users\Med\GolandProjects\ to store kubo project
4. In Settings In the GOROOT field I specified the location of my Go installation.
5. Selecting project (kubo) in context meny I pressed `Run` - it asked for configuration.
6. After I press Run on project it creates configuration:

[image]

Then following error message is shown:

> Error running 'go build github.com/ipfs/kubo': Cannot run program
> "C:\Users\Med\AppData\Local\Temp\GoLand___go_build_github_com_ipfs_kubo.exe"
> (in directory "C:\Users\Med\Go\kubo"): CreateProcess error=216, This
> version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're
> running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the
> software publisher

Search in Web says error 216 means
**mismatch in OS, ARCH**.

It creates small exe file that windows 10 cann't run.

I can build and run some small test programs withing kubo - but not thr whole project.

Go env:
C:\Users\Med\AppData\Local\Temp\GoLand>go env

> set GO111MODULE=
> set GOARCH=amd64
> set GOBIN=
> set GOCACHE=C:\Users\Med\AppData\Local\go-build
> set GOENV=C:\Users\Med\AppData\Roaming\go\env
> set GOEXE=.exe
> set GOEXPERIMENT=
> set GOFLAGS=
> set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
> set GOHOSTOS=windows
> set GOINSECURE=
> set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\Med\go\pkg\mod
> set GONOPROXY=
> set GONOSUMDB=
> set GOOS=windows
> set GOPATH=C:\Users\Med\go
> set GOPRIVATE=
> set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
> set GOROOT=D:\programs\Go
> set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
> set GOTMPDIR=
> set GOTOOLDIR=D:\programs\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
> set GOVCS=
> set GOVERSION=go1.19.1
> set GCCGO=gccgo
> set GOAMD64=v1
> set AR=ar
> set CC=gcc
> set CXX=g++
> set CGO_ENABLED=1
> set GOMOD=NUL
> set GOWORK=
> set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
> set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
> set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
> set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
> set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
> set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
> set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0
> -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\Med\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1544731977=/tmp/go-build
> -gno-record-gcc-switches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand why it works but it works:
**I selected kubo/cmd/ipfs item** in the project tree on the right pane and pressed Run from context menu. And Goland built (I think) main package, created executable of correct size (60Mb) and serves like daemon serves: I can connect via WebUI and I'm able to observe my previously uploaded files. But this is not daemon - during debug I see that it do not consider such launch as daemon and exits as batch process.
This is configuration that was automatically created:

[image]

Output of compilator:

```
GOROOT=C:\Users\Med\Go\go1.19.1 #gosetup
GOPATH=C:\Users\Med\Go #gosetup
C:\Users\Med\Go\go1.19.1\bin\go.exe build -o C:\Users\Med\AppData\Local\Temp\GoLand\___1go_build_github_com_ipfs_kubo_cmd_ipfs.exe -gcflags "all=-N -l" github.com/ipfs/kubo/cmd/ipfs #gosetup
```

But I'm still interested to understand the principles of Go/Goland build and I encourage others to give explanation based on this kubo example.